# Replace the values of two dataframe columns based on the values of a column of another data frame

Tags: r

I have the 2 dataframes below:

```
Names<-c("Max","Helen","Bob","Eva")
Id<-c(1,2,3,4)
LISTN<-data.frame(Names,Id)

Name1<-c("Max","Bob")
Name2<-c("Helen","Eva")
PAIRS<-data.frame(Name1,Name2)
```

I would like to replace the values of the columns `Name1` and `Name2` of the `PAIRS` with the respective `Id` found in the `LISTN`. The result should look like:

```
Name1 Name2
1     1     2
2     3     4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways using `match`, a function designed for converting ordered values into indexing positions:

```
> sapply(PAIRS, match, LISTN$Names)  # returns matrix
     Name1 Name2
[1,]     1     2
[2,]     3     4

> as.data.frame(lapply(PAIRS, match, LISTN$Names)) # returns dataframe
  Name1 Name2
1     1     2
2     3     4
```

If Names were not already ordered sequentially you would need to first address that.

Comment: I generally try to avoid destructive modification of existing data.

Comment: tnx I will use this

Comment: Or something like `Map(function(p,l,i) i[match(p,l)], PAIRS, LISTN["Names"], LISTN["Id"])` which indexes `LISTN["Id"]` explicitly, for use when the id's aren't just `1:4`

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse` you can do:

```
PAIRS %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 left_join(LISTN, by = c("val" = "Names")) %>%
 select(-val) %>%
 spread(var, Id) %>%
 select(-rowid)

  Name1 Name2
1     1     2
2     3     4
```

It is transforming the PAIRS df from wide to long format, merging it with LISTN df on names and then transforming it back to wide format with values from "Id".